# When building error "System.IO.IOException: The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid" in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I compiled and build my project it generated the following error **System.IO.IOException: The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid**

There were no changes between the last time that worked and the error.

> System.IO.IOException: The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.
>
> at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean >recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound, WIN32_FIND_DATA& data)
> at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean >recursive, Boolean checkHost)
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.RemoveDirFixed.RunTask()   ServLottery.Android

[image: Screenshot]

It's not related to an specific line of code.

Comment: which line in YOUR code is throwing the exception?

Comment: I have no idea, doesn't say much and doesn't do a thing if I double click it

Comment: is this happening when you build?  Because you didn't say that, so I assumed it was a run time error.  See https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/4104

Comment: `Reparsepoint` points to a Windows disk corruption issue relating to a driver, virus, hardware level problem.

Comment: Yes, happens when I build or clean

Comment: Nothing else has change in my pc other than that error @SushiHangover

Comment: @EstefaniaHernandez You can google/bing that error, it is related to a file structure mapping failure (rebooting in safe mode and using `chkdsk c: /f /r` to scan and try to fix the issues is normally a starting point). **BUT** I would advise you to backup your data first and then search for that error message **"The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid"** before doing anything that could be destructive to your data

Comment: I found something, the issue is in the following file ServLottery.Android/obj/Debug/90/lp/23/jl/res/interpolator-v21 it is not accessible and shows the error The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.

Comment: @EstefaniaHernandez You can clean the project(delete the `obj` and `bin` folder) and rebuild it to check whether can solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleted bin and obj folder from the Android project

Comment: Seems to help when Visual Studio upgrade breaks Blazor.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred for me when building in release configuration and trying to archive the project.

For me it was because the project was contained within a one drive folder. I moved the project to a root directory on my system and it built successfully.